# How to test Multiple MS Unit test project in Bamboo

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest, bamboo

I want to add multiple Ms unit test project in single solution in VS 2010 and want to execute all projects test case in single shot in Bamboo CI.

In Bamboo i am able to test Single project by using project dll but not able to execute Test written in multiple project .

I tried on google and found .vsmdi file will do that functionality but not crack how to all test cases add in to vsmdi file .

Please help me.

The Vsmdi File is look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestLists xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
<TestList name="Lists of Tests" id="8c43106b-9dc1-4907-a29f-aa66a61bf5b6">
  <RunConfiguration id="68cd1a40-fbe7-4a52-bc91-47f0ca5ea70a" name="Local" storage="local.testsettings" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRunConfiguration, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</TestList>
</TestLists>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Adding a vsmdi file is well documented. Once added the tests are autodiscovered and added to the test lists in the vsdmi

Comment: When i have add multiple test case in multiple project the .vsmdi project created by system not contain all test case entry.I have update vsmdi xml in question please see.

Comment: Have you built the solution and then clicked on "Refresh" in the test list editor tab??